# Pausing Main Thread Until Event Is Fired

Tags: c#

I have a small console utility that utilizes a custom parsing library (not modifiable by me) to parse some files. As the parser does its job, it raises `StatusChanged` events. In my `Main` function, I attached a handler to this event so I can perform some tasks when the event is fired.

```
parser.StatusChanged += OnStatusChanged;
```

However, I'm running into a problem because the `Main` thread doesn't wait to exit until the event is fired. How do I allow the `Main` thread to terminate only based on some execution in the `OnStatusChanged` handler? This handler may be called whenever the status changes, but I want the program to exit only when the status reaches `Done`.

Currently, instead of waiting for the event to fire, I have a loop in `Main` that loops (and does nothing) until the parser reaches a status of `Done`, but this seems like the wrong approach. Further, when running in Release mode, it looks like this loop never terminates for some reason. It works fine in Debug mode.

```
while (parser.Status != ParserStatus.Done) { };
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. while(true) may seem dirty, but that really IS the intended functionality. No need for any magic abort handling either, CTRL+C will terminate the loop implicitly :)

Comment: Presumably this library raises these events on a worker thread, use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to verify.  You need an AutoResetEvent to signal your main thread.  Putting the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method might have an affect as well.

Comment: @HansPassant `AutoResetEvent` was what I was looking for, thanks! Now, after I start the parser, I wait for the `OnStatusChanged` handler to signal the event before proceeding. Works like a charm! If you want to post this as the answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop isn't that far off, You just need to add a wait so it doesn't just spin as fast as it can :

```
while (parser.Status != ParserStatus.Done) {
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 second - adjust to an appropriate value ... 
}
```

You might want to implement a simple timeout for this to avoid it going on forever, which is easy :

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

while (parser.Status != ParserStatus.Done || sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > A_TIMEOUT) {
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 second 
}
```

Comment: For a whole second!?!?!? :P

Comment: @Davesoft Eh? ... a second is a pretty long time? :/

Comment: Can be. You're answer is essentially what I commented, only nicely worded and with examples :)